# PyArrayObject definition is missing

Tags: python, c, numpy

I'm trying to compile some C code (CUDA) [1], which relies on Numpy package:

```
/cuda-convnet-vs-proj/src/util.cu(69): error : identifier "PyArrayObject" is undefined
```

I installed Anaconda (on Windows), which includes Python 2.7 and Numpy package. 
util.cu includes header util.cuh, which includes Python.h.

I'm not even sure if this is a problem in the code (missing definition or header file), or Visual Studio is not looking in the right place.

I'm a beginner, how do I troubleshoot this?

Here's the code that refers to PyArrayObject:

```
#include <util.cuh>
using namespace std;

MatrixV* getMatrixV(PyObject* pyList) {
    if (pyList == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    MatrixV* vec = new MatrixV(); 
    for (int i = 0; i < PyList_GET_SIZE(pyList); i++) {
        vec->push_back(new Matrix((PyArrayObject*)PyList_GET_ITEM(pyList, i)));
    }
    return vec;
}
```

And util.cuh header contains the line:

```
#include <Python.h>
```

[1] http://www.asiteof.me/archives/50

Comment: Could you show the code snippet where `PyArrayObjec` is declared?

Comment: Please take a look (code added)

Comment: I do not see the declaration or definition of `PyArrayObjec` in this code.

Comment: Well, my understanding is that it should be defined in one of the numpy header files, which are accessible from util.cuh -> Python.h.  Here's some info about this object: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.types-and-structures.html

Comment: I suspect about mixed type declaration. MSVC does't allow this and gives warning like you are getting.

Comment: Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Declare all the variables in the the beginning of your code in C89 style (but I think `PyArrayObjec` is a structure here and it would not work).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by including ndarraytypes.h, which defines PyArrayObject.